# Simple question of how models deal with control variables

Tags: r, model, controlling-for-a-variable

Apologies for the very simple question, it's something I've had trouble wrapping my head around: How does a model (e.g. logistic regression) deal with control variables - if the purpose is to keep a control variable constant, how does it choose which level (of that variable) to keep constant, or does it run the model for every level of that variable and somehow produce a single output?

For example:
Say I have an opportunistic dataset of locations where birds have put their nests. I've put an example sample below, but pretend there are many more data points. My dependent variable is the "Location" of the bird's nest, and the independent variable is the "Weather" and "Distance to water" - I want to see whether these factors influence the choice of location for their nest. I know that "Year" and "Species (of bird)" will also influence this, however as I am not studying those factors I want to control for them.

Will the model, therefore, run on every possible combination of keeping both Year and Species constant (i.e. Species CB, the Year 2018. Species CB, the Year 2019 ... Species ETD, Year. 2018)?

| Species | Location | Weather | Year | Distance to water (m) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CB | A | Rain | 2019 | 12 |
| CB | B | Rain | 2019 | 2 |
| ETD | B | Dry | 2020 | 18 |
| ER | A | Dry | 2018 | 7 |
| ETD | B | Rain | 2020 | 16 |
| CB | A | Rain | 2018 | 23 |
| ER | A | Rain | 2018 | 9 |
| ER | B | Dry | 2020 | 10 |

Or does the model do fancy statistics to determine which combination of control variables will lead to significance for the non-control variables? Please explain this in terms of what RSTUDIO does.

Comment: RStudio is an Integrated Development Environment not a model, and it is your model which will answer whether it runs on every possible combination of Year and Species or whether it treats them as having separate additive effects on the log-odds of Locations.  With some functions, considering every combination would come from code containing something like  `Year*Species` while `Year+Species` would not do this

Comment: Okay, do you know how binomial logistic regression would be treated? Or know a good resource for me to look into that? I'm new to all this so something in not too complex language would be helpful.